# How does Facebook user ID work?

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I would like to check roughly when an user joined Facebook using Facebook Graph API and FQL. I noticed that the early Facebook members have small ID, while the late joiners have larger ID.

Can we estimate the time a member join Facebook by looking at their ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You're right, with some ID's (people who signed up the first few years of FB) you theoretically could. But then you'd need an intimate knowledge of FB growth rates at various times to determine the actual estimated time range.

But now, you cannot. Each object on Facebook has a globally unique ID. Each User, Page, Group, Post, Photo, Video, etc are all unique ids. So it would be impractical to try to determine the time-range now.

Comment: Thanks Tommy. That's what I would like to confirm.